# Quikwall parge showing blotches

Tags: basement, foundation

We recently parged our basement walls using quikwall parge mix. The concrete is now 50 days old and we are planning on painting it with drylok. However, there is one splotch that still looks wet. This area was a particularly moist section of the foundation before we parged.

Outside of the house there is nothing that should make this corner any wetter than anywhere else. We had the yard re-graded when we moved in last summer. That said, the height of the splotch is below grade.

Here are two photos:

[image]
[image]

My questions are:

1. What is causing this splotch?
2. Will painting it fix it or just cover up the problem?
3. If painting isn't the solution, what is?

Comment: How do you know there is not a problem in that area? There was a wet spot there to start with and there is one after all the inside work, sounds like a spring if summer or a not so good sealing job on the outside. I have worked on jobs that we totally excavated the exterior , steam pressure washed the exterior , applied guaranteed coatings as an approved company and had the coating fail even with 100% gravel back fill and multiple foundation drains. In this case the coating company paid for a total retrofit that also had a failure, below grade so just trying inside is a waste in my experiance.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, but I don't know that it is a wet spot. It feels dry. Are you saying the parge is wet? There will be a wet spot in the future? 

As for there not being a problem, I just meant that outside of the house there is nothing suspicious. Its properly graded, gutters drain away from there, its on the downhill side of the house, etc.

Comment: Below grade what is there? If there was a wet spot prior to the parge work and it looks like it is wet now this sounds like a suspicious. Area to me. To find out about floors if there is moisture we tape some plastic to the floor sealing at least a square foot or more, after 24 hours pull the plastic off the wall and if the plastic is damp there is a moisture problem, give this a try to get a better idea if there is a problem.

Comment: Was there ever an underground heating oil tank?

Comment: Update: I did the plastic test for 48 hours and there was no moisture on the plastic. I don't know if there was an underground heating oil tank. The house is in Denver CO and is 100 years old. The previous owners didn't even know if the pipes were galvanized (they were) so I am going on basically no knowlege about old parts of the house.

Comment: Did you ever learn more? We parged a 10’ section of wall with quikwall and had a few 5-10” spots like this. It remained exposed and unpainted for 4 months and never changed. Was not damp and plastic test showed no moisture. It’s all been Drylok’d now. For the first few weeks I was certain it was wet and bummed that the repointing and parge weren’t done properly, but it’s been dry.

Comment: It's been 2 years now with Drylok paint over the parge and there is no blotching or wetness showing through. My best guess is that the quikwall just cure with some kind of darker coloring sometimes? We have no had any issues since we painted and there have been some very crazy storms since then.